# GnuCobol compiler COBC does not work correctly with -I option for NFS mounted disks

Tags: nfs, gnucobol

I try to compile cbl file that includes statement like

```
01 WS02-RETURN-STATUS COPY "boolind.ef"..
    COPY "boolind.va".
```

Both files (boolind.ef and boolind.va) location is NOT local disk

```
df -k /clchome/clc/ccclc/mb_ccclc/proj/clb134/clcgdd

Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
isiloncorp1:/dev_storage 1073741824 373998592 699743232 35% /AMD/DEV/storage
```

When i run compilation like

```
cobc -c fcd_demo.cbl -I/clchome/clc/ccclc/mb_ccclc/proj/clb134/clcgdd
```

I receive an error like

```
fcd_demo.cbl:57: error: boolind.ef: No such file or directory
```

but when I copy file boolind.ef to local directory or to /tmp
it works good.
How to use "include" on not local disk ?
Could you help ?

I have tried to use -ext option...
Unfortunately it does not help.
When I try to add something like –ext=ef I receive the same compilation error.
Interesting that it happens when "copybook files" location is NFS disk only.
When I copy them to local disk it works well.

```
I mean : cobc –c myfile.cbl –I/tmp/ttt
```

Maybe exists some option that allows to use NFS ?